# Mongoose .save very slow large sub-document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We are facing a very annoying issue with Mongoose.
The `save` method takes around 500 / 600ms and it is very CPU consuming.

We have a sub-document with 50000 array elements which gets a new element (history) every each update using push.

Here is the code:

```
..... very large function 

variable.value = parseFloat(value);
variable.history.push([{
        value: parseFloat(value),
        timestamp: dateNow
}]);
await variable.save(); 
..... end function
```

I have indexes on history and _id.

Any hint on why this is taking so long and consuming 60%...80% CPU ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and looked all over and there doesn't seem to be a reasonable solution other than modifying your schema.

My save function would take very long after the document had a large sub-document array with over 100K entries.

I removed the array from the document and created a new schema, so instead of pushing to the sub-document array, I created a new one.

Comment: I am facing the same problem! It is pretty slow when in sub-document, I will have to keep the document approach I had originally done.